# Display video list Order by Most comment and most Favorite in Youtube API v3

Tags: java, android, youtube-data-api

I want to display videos list order by Most comment and most favorite in my application where I am using youtube API v3.

These filter criteria is available in youtube api v3.If there is no api then is there any other way to filter video in these criteria.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you have response from video search you can get no. of comments and favorite count like below.

```
YouTube.Videos.List searchvideostats = youtube.videos().list("snippet,statistics");
searchvideostats.setKey(apiKey);
List<video> videos = searchvideostats.execute().getItems();

for(Video v:videos){
BigInteger commentcount = v.getStatistics().getCommentCount();
BigInteger fouvritecount = v.getStatistics().getFavoriteCount();
}
```

Store these counts in some collection, then run your custom comparison method by overwriting compare() of `Comparator` class like.

```
public int compare(VideoDetails o1, VideoDetails o2) {
    int cmntcmp = o2.getNo_of_comments().compareTo(o1.getNo_of_comments());
    if (cmntcmp != 0) {
      return cmntcmp;
    } else {
      int fvrtcmp = o2.getNo_of_favourite().compareTo(o1.getNo_of_favourite());

      return fvrtcmp;
    }
  }
```